# Add circled letters in titles

Tags: sectioning

In my course, I would like to specify the level of each sub-part using the levels indicated in circles.

If I use the command `\section{title} \trf` , the circled letters appear below the title.

If I place them in the \section{XX} command like `\section{title \trf}` , the document does not compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\newcommand{\atrf}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!red] (letter) {ATRF};}
\newcommand{\trf}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!blue] (letter) {TRF};}
\newcommand{\asi}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!orange] (letter) {ASI};}

\begin{document}
\section{Chapitre 1} \asi \trf
\section{Chapitre 2}
\subsection{Sous section 2.1}
\subsection{Sous section 2.2}

\end{document}
```

How to make levels appear in the title line (and therefore appear in the table of contents as well)

Comment: Try `\section[Chapitre 1 (ASI) (TRF)]{Chapitre 1 \asi \trf`}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be cautions when using macros inside section titles, because these titles will appear at several other places in the document, such as in PDF bookmarks or in the page headers or footers.

Still, it is possible to use macros, but you need to provide an alternative macro-less version of the title in the optional argument of the `\section` macro (the same holds for similar macros, such as `\chapter`, `\subsection` etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\newcommand{\atrf}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!red] (letter) {ATRF};}
\newcommand{\trf}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!blue] (letter) {TRF};}
\newcommand{\asi}{\tikz[baseline=(letter.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!10!orange] (letter) {ASI};}

\begin{document}
\section[Chapitre 1 (ASI) (TRF)]{Chapitre 1 \asi \trf}
\section{Chapitre 2}
\subsection{Sous section 2.1}
\subsection{Sous section 2.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'd avoid code duplication: your commands can be defined in terms of a two-argument command, that supplies the needed Ti*k*Z instructions and can be made into something different when typesetting the table of contents (unless you want the balls also there).

Next, define such commands as robust ones, so they'll survive being in a moving argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\newcommand{\shadedball}[2]{% #1 = color, #2 = acronym
  \ifintoc
    (\textcolor{black!10!#1}{#2})%
  \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!10!#1,
      minimum width=3em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}
\newif\ifintoc

\DeclareRobustCommand{\atrf}{\shadedball{red}{ARTF}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\trf}{\shadedball{blue}{TRF}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\asi}{\shadedball{orange}{ASI}}

\begin{document}

\intoctrue
\tableofcontents
\intocfalse

\section{Chapitre 1 \asi\ \trf\ \atrf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the conditional business

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\newcommand{\shadedball}[2]{% #1 = color, #2 = acronym
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!10!#1,
      minimum width=3em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\atrf}{\shadedball{red}{ARTF}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\trf}{\shadedball{blue}{TRF}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\asi}{\shadedball{orange}{ASI}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Chapitre 1 \asi\ \trf\ \atrf}

\end{document}
```

[image]